# merge a tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following data that I need to merge:

```
tuples = ('ziyao','sa'),('guilog','sa'),('yiping','pe'),('tom','pesa'),('haha','pesa'),('hehe','pesa')
```

The output I want is:

```
tuples = [('ziyao','guilog','sa'),('yiping','pe'),('tom','haha','hehe','pesa')] # or 'ziyao','guilog','sa'\n'yiping','pe'\n...
```

Comment: You completely changed the question.

Comment: It doesn't make sense yet, what is the logic of the output grouping?

Comment: How exactly you want to group?? based on the second element of every tuple?

Comment: You're going to have to be way more precise. I can think of at least 3 algorithms that would give you the output you want on the given input and they'd each do something distinct on other input. I have no idea what you want.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want a dictionary instead?

Answer (score 4):

I think I understand what he means...

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> tuples = ('ziyao','sa'),('guilog','sa'),('yiping','pe'),('tom','pesa'),('haha','pesa'),('hehe','pesa')
>>> [list(zip(*v)[0]) + [k] for k,v in groupby(tuples,lambda x: x[1])]
[['ziyao', 'guilog', 'sa'], ['yiping', 'pe'], ['tom', 'haha', 'hehe', 'pesa']]
```

Comment: Hahahha, your question was good at the end but don't constantly change your question or you will get lots of downvotes ;)

Comment: I was a novice, I will pay attention to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
by_second = defaultdict(list)
for first, second in input_tuples:
    by_second[second].append(first)
output_tuples = [tuple(v) + (k,) for k,v in by_second.iteritems()]
```

Comment: It doesn't even solve what exactly the user had described in the question

Comment: @Surya the OP edited their question. It did solve what was originally asked.